# How does siglongjmp work with multiple signal handlers

Tags: signals

I am following the [APUE textbook on `siglongjump()`](https://notes.shichao.io/apue/ch10/#sigsetjmp-and-siglongjmp-functions), and there is this [piece of code](https://github.com/shichao-an/apue.3e/blob/master/signals/mask.c) which is confusing me.

- `pr_mask()` is simply a function which prints the signals which are masked.
- According to this, if `USR1` signal comes, it gets added to the process mask and this is the handler.

  ```C
  static void
  sig_usr1(int signo)
  {
      time_t  starttime;

      if (canjump == 0)
          return;     /* unexpected signal, ignore */

      pr_mask("starting sig_usr1: ");

      alarm(3);               /* SIGALRM in 3 seconds */
      starttime = time(NULL);
      for ( ; ; )             /* busy wait for 5 seconds */
          if (time(NULL) > starttime + 5)
              break;

      pr_mask("finishing sig_usr1: ");

      canjump = 0;
      siglongjmp(jmpbuf, 1);  /* jump back to main, don't return */
  }
  ```
- Now while `USR1` is processing, `SIG_ALARM` comes, it will call the handler

  ```C
  static void
  sig_alrm(int signo)
  {
      pr_mask("in sig_alrm: ");
  }
  ```

  and this `SIG_ALARM` will also get added to the proc mask. However, when `sig_alarm()` is done, then `SIG_ALARM` is going to be removed from the proc mask. This is illustrated when the call to `pr_mask("finishing sig_usr1: ");` is made in `sig_usr1()`.

How is `SIG_ALARM` not masked when `pr_mask("finishing sig_usr1")` is called? `siglongjump()` should only restore the old mask when `siglongjump()` is called, which happens after this call.